# how to choose/design a capacitor value for surge current(for protection) for DC brush motor?

Tags: motor, dc, lm317

I am driving a DC BRUSH Motor at 30.V.D.C and the current is 300 Millie ampere, it is powered by L.M.317 I.C .My sir is suggesting to provide a capacitor as a protection form surge/peak current resulting from the motor when it gets on initially. capacitor should be placed in between motor and regulator(l.m.317) I.C.
Can any one help me how to calculate this capacitor value with formula and what all parameters i need to consider?

Comment: If you switch the power off while the motor is running, the BEMF can be higher than input voltage of LM317. Perhaps you need a backflow diode, too.

Comment: @Marko Buršič rightly said! sir i have taken care for it.i have connected the protection circuit for LM317.